# Does button onlick inline JS need apostrophes (or double quotes)?

Tags: javascript, html

This works: `<button onclick='f(arg)'></button>`

This also works (on Firefox): `<button onclick=f(arg)></button>` (ie. no apostrophes or double quotes).

But I wonder if no apostrophes or double quotes works in general (eg. for other browsers)?

Comment: Only if there's a space in the attribute. But there's a much, much better approach: don't use inline JS, attach listeners properly using JavaScript instead of putting it in the HTML markup

Comment: How is that much better?

Comment: * No need to rely on global variables * No [demented scope chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045) * No need to work around tedious quote escaping issues

Comment: Thanks, CertainPerformance!